# Is there a way to get XML content from an API in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, openlayers

I created a Web API in C# to return XML document, actually there is a base url and I post something to it as body of a `HttpWebRequest`, and as a result, I will get response that is pure XML but as string.

So I need to send this response to client but the `Content-Type` of response is `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. It should be `text/xml` or `application/xml`, I've tried some xml parser like `XDocument.Parse("myXml")` and `XElement.Parse("myXml")`, but the type was 'text' and 'json'.

I also tried `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter` but at this moment the type gets correct but the body consists of other characters like this `&lt;` should be '<' or `&gt` be '>':

```
<string>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" ...</string>
```

Well this is my code on the API side:

```
public dynamic Get()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    // request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8";
    // request.Accept = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
         stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    return responseString;    // text type at postman app
    return XDocument.Parse(responseString);   // json type in Postman app
}
```

Comment: Did I get you right that you created the Web API, but instead of the expected response it delivers something unexpected. So the problem is probably be at the server code, not the client side.

Comment: Yes, exactly the problem is at server side.

Comment: There is nothing wrong.  Your xml is being sent as inner text inside an HTML tag and special characters need to be encoded to meet HTML requirements.  You can use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) to remove the special character encoding.